# How to disable the landscape mode on iPhone but keep it on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to only use portrait mode on iPhone, but both portrait and landscape on iPad, is this possible?

I'm using Swift, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just quick look at this screenshots.

[image]

[image]

This means you have different orientations settings for device types (Also you can change it is settings.plist).

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that, thanks